# Jest snapshot testing - ignore react auto generated markup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Many of our snapshots are broken after migrating from react 15 to 16 due to [SSR markup improvements](https://hackernoon.com/whats-new-with-server-side-rendering-in-react-16-9b0d78585d67), for example text wrappers:

```
<!-- react-text: 1 -->Text<!-- /react-text -->
```

Have been removed in react 16.

Of course i could update the snapshots but I need to know if they're failing due to markup changes or actual regressions.

Is it possible to configure Jest to ignore React's auto-generated markup?